# Фильтр навигации на jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Не могу разобраться.
Есть больше 10 блоков и навигация из 4 пунктов. Каждому блоку присвоена одна из 4 групп. Как сделать так, что бы при клике на один из пунктов навигации - не меняли стиль только те блоки, которые относятся к этой группе, а всем остальным - добавлялся класс (например "**disabled**") ? При переключении на другой пункт - уже другие блоки остаются, а всем другим добавлялся класс ("**disabled**") ?

Comment: Попробуйте написать код сами и дайте сюда пример если будут ошибки. Я же дам вам вариант решения. Попробуйте запустить цикл прохода по всем 10-ти блокам, например по их классу, сделав его уникальным. В каждом проходе стоит IF и проверяет равен ли этот класс выбранной группе или нет. Если равен не добавляем, иначе добавляем класс на скритие. Напомню что пройти по классам можно с помощью `.each()`, триггер класса `.toggleClass()`, остальное свободно описано в интернете.

Comment: @Levelleor спасибо, погуглю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В примере только по одному блоку, но сделано так чтобы работать с множеством элементов -

```js
let nav = document.querySelector( '#navbar' );

const nav_changeHandler = () => changeRoute(  );

nav.addEventListener( 'change', nav_changeHandler );


function changeRoute(  ){
 let route = document.querySelector( `input[type=radio]:checked` ).dataset.rout;
 let prevRoutes = document.querySelectorAll( `[data-active="true"]` );

 if( prevRoutes.length ){
  hideRoute( prevRoutes );
 }

 let currentRoute = document.querySelectorAll( `[data-route="${ route }"]` );

 showRoute( currentRoute );
}

function showRoute( routes ){
 for( let route of routes ){
  route.hidden = false;
  route.dataset.active = true;
 }
}
function hideRoute( routes ){
 for( let route of routes ){
  route.dataset.active = false;
 }
}

changeRoute();
```

```css
.navbar-horizontal {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;

  pointer-events: none;
}
.nav > li {
  list-style: none;
}

.horizontal-list {
  position: absolute;
  
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.horizontal-list-item {
  float: left;
}

.nav-item {
 width: auto;
   height: 20px;
  
    padding: 5px 6px; 
  
    position: relative;
  
    ext-align: center;
}

.router {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;

 position: fixed;

 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}

[data-route="bisque"] {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;

 background: bisque;
}
[data-route="mintcream"] {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;

 background: mintcream;
}
[data-route="aquamarine"] {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;

 background: aquamarine;
}
[data-route="burlywood"] {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;

 background: burlywood;
}

label {
 cursor: pointer;
 pointer-events: auto;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  
  padding: 3px 0;
}

[data-active="false"] {
 display: none;
}
[data-active="true"] {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="router">
 <div class="route" data-route="bisque" data-active="false"></div>
 <div class="route" data-route="mintcream" data-active="false"></div>
 <div class="route" data-route="aquamarine" data-active="false"></div>
 <div class="route" data-route="burlywood" data-active="false"></div>
</div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-horizontal" id="navbar">
  <ul class="nav horizontal-list" id=navbar-nav>
    <li class="horizontal-list-item nav-item">
      <input type="radio" id="nav-item_0" name="nav" data-rout="bisque" hidden checked>
      <label for="nav-item_0">bisque</label>
    </li>
    <li class="horizontal-list-item nav-item">
      <input type="radio" id="nav-item_1" name="nav" data-rout="mintcream" hidden>
      <label for="nav-item_1">mintcream</label>
    </li>
    <li class="horizontal-list-item nav-item">
      <input type="radio" id="nav-item_2" name="nav" data-rout="aquamarine" hidden>
      <label for="nav-item_2">aquamarine</label>
    </li>
    <li class="horizontal-list-item nav-item">
      <input type="radio" id="nav-item_3" name="nav" data-rout="burlywood" hidden>
      <label for="nav-item_3">burlywood</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Спасибо! То, что нужно